# Google Cloud SQL disable Table Name Case Sensitivity

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Is there a way to change the setting to disable table name case sensitivity?  I know that in the .cnf all you have to do is add this;

```
lower_case_table_names = 1
```

Although I cannot seem to find a way to do that.  Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it either from the Developers Console or from the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/):

**Developers Console**

1. Go to the [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com) and click on your project.
2. Go to Storage -> Cloud SQL -> select your instance and click on 'Edit'.
3. In the MySQL Flags section, click on 'Choose a Flag' and select `lower_case_table_names`.
4. Two new text boxes are appended to your MySQL FLAGS. Type in the right text box: `1`.
5. Save the changes.

**Cloud SDK**

You can install the Cloud SDK in your computer and run these commands:

1. `gcloud auth login`
2. `gcloud sql instances patch YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME --database-flags lower_case_table_names=1 --project YOUR_PROJECT_ID`

You can find more information about the supported [MySQL flags in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-flags).

Answer (score 2):

You can set it in the "advance options" section for the Cloud SQL instance at Google Developers Console (sorry I don't have enough reputation to post images...)

For an existing instance, you need to restart it for the flag to take effect.